Get crosses created by linear-gradient in front of span background
the following html/css creates:

the difference is only in the span style using a background-color in the second cell.
You can see, that the crosses are then behind the text and the background-color.
I can not use pseudo elements because sometimes inline styles have to be used (do not ask why this is asked for, it is just wanted in special circumstances)
I tried a bit around with z-index but had no success.
Is there a way to get the crosses in the foreground? Best with only changing the td style?
The cell may have any backcolor and the span may have any backcolor
Thanks for any idea


<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 56.7pt; border: 1px solid red;
                        background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 49.9%, black 50%, black 52%, transparent 52.1%, transparent 100%), 
                            linear-gradient(to right top, transparent 0%, transparent 49.9%, blue 50%, blue 51%, transparent 51.1%, transparent 100%);
                        background-color: green;
                        background-size: 100% 100%;
                         background-clip: padding-box;">
        <p>
          <span style=" color: #000000;">Content</span>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 56.7pt;  border: 1px solid red;
                        background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 49.9%, black 50%, black 52%, transparent 52.1%, transparent 100%), 
                            linear-gradient(to right top, transparent 0%, transparent 49.9%, blue 50%, blue 51%, transparent 51.1%, transparent 100%);
                        background-color: green;
                        background-size: 100% 100%;
                         background-clip: padding-box;">
        <p>
          <span style="background: #FF00FF; color: #000000;">Content</span>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 56.7pt;  border: 1px solid red;
                        background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 49.9%, black 50%, black 52%, transparent 52.1%, transparent 100%), 
                            linear-gradient(to right top, transparent 0%, transparent 49.9%, blue 50%, blue 51%, transparent 51.1%, transparent 100%);
                        background-color: grey;
                        background-size: 100% 100%;
                         background-clip: padding-box;">
        <p>
          <span style="background: #FF00FF; color: #000000;">Content</span>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




You can get part way there (and in a way the user may not notice) by putting mix-blend-mode: darken on the span. But of course it depends on the relationship between the background color and cross - you'd always be OK if the cross was black, In the case you have given the blue diagonal shows up over the magenta color but is just behind the actual characters.

can you explain, and give an example, of why you need inline styles sometimes?

@AHaworth
the crossdiagonals will always be black, the blue was only for better seeing.
I tested it, it works if the background is white but if the cellbackground is eg. green the pink will change to black

@AHaworth inlinestyles are asked from the customer and have to be made for some taggers. I think, it is absolutley strange but what can you do if it is mandatory asked for.

Can you add the possibility of a color background to the td into your example so we have the more general picture? Plus the cross always being black may be helpful.

@AHaworth
I changed the example.
The cell may have any backcolor and the span may have any backcolor and any color

When you say inline may be used, can you say on what elements? Is it really going to be used on the td? If so, to what effect?

@AHaworth
I have to put my questions better.
when using inline styles all elements use inline styles.
The requirement is not to use any css classes, neither as style-sheet nor in the head.

Thanks, understood - I guess it's for the sort of problem e.g. caused by email clients.

There is a rather hacky way of doing this, involving perspective and needing to add some styling to the p element not just the td element. Is that acceptable?

@AHaworth thanks for your engagement. I think it could be to complicated (I'm working with the OpenXmlPowertools hacking them :-). It is now agreed, that we live with the problem of Highlights. But me personally would be interessted to try the hack. So I would appreciate if you could show. (Perhaps there is still a future way to implement it to the current project). Thank you anyway for your help and patience.

I do not think that you can get the desired result altering only the td styles. The reason being that you have to separate out the cross background image from the plain color background. They must not be in the same plain so the child elements can be slipped between the two.
This snippet therefore uses perspective-3d and puts the td background color on the child element, simulated with a large box-shadow which then gets clipped - the horizontal sides through a clip path on the child itself and the vertical with a clip on the tr.
Yes, it's hacky but it does work for the given code.


<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);">
      <td style="width: 56.7pt; border: 1px solid red;
                    background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 49.9%, black 50%, black 52%, transparent 52.1%, transparent 100%), 
                        linear-gradient(to right top, transparent 0%, transparent 49.9%, blue 50%, blue 51%, transparent 51.1%, transparent 100%);
                    background-size: 100% 100%;
                    background-clip: padding-box;
                    transform-style: preserve-3d;
                    --bg: green;">
        <p style="clip-path: polygon(-2px -100vmax, calc(100% + 2px) -100vmax, calc(100% + 2px) 100vmax, -2px 100vmax); transform: translateZ(-1px); background-color: var(--bg); box-shadow: 0px 0px 0 100vmax var(--bg);">
          <span style=" color: #000000;">Content</span>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 56.7pt;  border: 1px solid red;
                    background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 49.9%, black 50%, black 52%, transparent 52.1%, transparent 100%), 
                        linear-gradient(to right top, transparent 0%, transparent 49.9%, blue 50%, blue 51%, transparent 51.1%, transparent 100%);
                    background-size: 100% 100%;
                    background-clip: padding-box;
                    transform-style: preserve-3d;
                    --bg: green;
                    ">
        <p style="clip-path: polygon(-2px -100vmax, calc(100% + 2px) -100vmax, calc(100% + 2px) 100vmax, -2px 100vmax); transform: translateZ(-1px); background-color: var(--bg); box-shadow: 0px 0px 0 100vmax var(--bg);">
          <span style="background: #FF00FF; color: #000000;">Content</span>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 56.7pt;  border: 1px solid red;
                    background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 49.9%, black 50%, black 52%, transparent 52.1%, transparent 100%), 
                        linear-gradient(to right top, transparent 0%, transparent 49.9%, blue 50%, blue 51%, transparent 51.1%, transparent 100%);
                    background-size: 100% 100%;
                     background-clip: padding-box;
                    transform-style: preserve-3d;
                    --bg: grey;">
        <p style="clip-path: polygon(-2px -100vmax, calc(100% + 2px) -100vmax, calc(100% + 2px) 100vmax, -2px 100vmax); transform: translateZ(-1px); background-color: var(--bg); box-shadow: 0px 0px 0 100vmax var(--bg);">
          <span style="background: #FF00FF; color: #000000;">Content</span>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




Wow, I will need some time to understand this. But I think it is brilliant. I will now experiment with it. I'm not very deep in CSS but it seems in the last 20 years a lot of magic where added :-).
Thank you so much for your time and effort.

Use pseudo-element and remove the inline styles:


td {
  width: 56.7pt;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
}

td:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background-image: 
   linear-gradient(to right bottom, #0000 49.9%, black 50% 52%,#0000 52.1%), 
   linear-gradient(to right top,    #0000 49.9%, blue  50% 51%,#0000 51.1%);
  pointer-events: none;
}
<table>
  <tr>
    <td >
      <p>
        <span style=" color: #000000;">Content</span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td >
      <p>
        <span style="background: #FF00FF; color: #000000;">Content</span>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>




I explained that I have to use inline styles,  i think it is ... but this is not negotiable

@RedHare you explained nothing. you simply said "sometimes inline styles have to be used" which is not a valid reason. Other people seeing this question will know that pseudo-element is the right solution. You can always ignore the answer, it will be helpful for other people.

I said also that I can not use pseudo-elements because of the inline-style neccessary.
I know that pseudoelements are the correct solution but can not be used in inline styles.
Sorry, if i did not explained it better, but in occasions, which i have no saying in, the inlinestyles are mandatory. I hate it myself.
And I wrote ths comment, because I like to flag an answer as solution and want to tell, why I can not flag it as solution. Sorry if I offended you.
